# Add Color Palette to ASP.NET Textbox

Tags: javascript, asp.net, textbox

I need to add a color palette to my form so the user could select specific text inside a normal text box then choose a color from the palette.

Then I would add a prefix like HTML tag before the selected text and after so when the text is rebound into a div or any other HTML controls the user could see the text in choosen color.

I hope to do so without using the AJAXControlToolkit.

Answer (score 2):

You can do this with jQuery if you don't mind using jQuery:

Having an regular text input element like so:

```
<input type="text" maxlength="6" size="6" id="colorpickerField1" value="00ff00">
```

You can create a Color picker doing:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/colorpicker.js"></script>

$(document).ready(function(){
   $('#colorpickerField1').ColorPicker({
    onSubmit: function(hsb, hex, rgb, el) {
        $(el).val(hex);
        $(el).ColorPickerHide();
    },
    onBeforeShow: function () {
        $(this).ColorPickerSetColor(this.value);
    }
   })
    .bind('keyup', function(){
        $(this).ColorPickerSetColor(this.value);
      });
});
```

And colorpicker.js can be downloaded [from here.](http://www.eyecon.ro/colorpicker/)

Comment: I do try to use colorpicker plugin but when I select a text then click on the button or whatever html element I used as "colorpickerField" I loose the selected content!! 
So I cannt catch the selection !